# Another box sliding up a ramp question

Tags: physics, vector-analysis

This is the problem:

> A woman exerts a horizontal force of 9 pounds on a box as she pushes
>   it up a ramp that is 6 feet long and inclined at an angle of 35
>   degrees above the horizontal.
>
> First state the displacement vector and the force vector, considering
>   the ramp going up from left to right and the level ground under the
>   ramp to be the positive x-axis.

This is how I've solved it. Since the problem says "horizontal" force, I've assumed her force vector over the displacement to look like this:

\begin{align}
\langle 9,0\rangle,\tag{1}
\end{align}
which makes sense. No problems there.

Now when it comes to the displacement vector, why is it that in this case, the following is wrong?

\begin{align}
\bigg\langle 6\cos\left(\frac{35\pi}{180}\right),6\sin\left(\frac{35\pi}{180}\right)\bigg\rangle\tag{2}
\end{align}

Thanks,

Comment: Since you know it's wrong, do you know what it's supposed to be?

Comment: @Arthur No, unfortunately I do not know the answer they want. I'm really frustrated and didn't know what else to do but post here and get others' interpretations. It looks like the problem's flaw to me, unless I'm making some drastic mis-interpretation. If it's not my problem though, I would say this is a testament to educator's abilities to not make a problem clear. They're always *so* vague. And that's not to say they don't spend a lot of time stating the obvious.